# Can i use another type of de valuset in code property distinct to type indicate in the Group resource definition?

Tags: resources, hl7-fhir, group

It is correct to use the Group resource code, with a valueset different from the Kind of Group members GroupKind. For example to use a valueset of programs with which a group of patients is served.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group.code has a binding strength of example.  You're welcome to use any valueset you like there.  (On the other hand Group.type has a 'required' binding, so you are limited to only the specified codes.)